# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader' in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a Class in C#, and my code is showing an error.
Error is =>**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader'**

I am getting error at **return SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(CnSettings.cnString1, CommandType.Text, commandText);**

```
public OracleDataReader getWeightmntInfoForCenter(string startdate, string enddate, string unitcode)
{
   string commandText = string.Concat(new string[]
   {
      "select m.unitcode unit_code, to_char(tran_date, 'dd-MON-yy') m_date,
      to_char(m_purchy) m_number, net AS n_weight, to_number(substr(g.ryot_code,5))
      m_grow, to_number(substr(g.ryot_code,1,4)) m_vill, g.mob g_phoneno, 
      m.s_purchy indent_number from sisl_purpurchase m,cn_ryot_mst g where 
      m.unitcode=g.unit_code and lpad(v_code,4,0)||lpad(f_code,5,0)=g.ryot_code And
      length(g.mob)=10 And m.tran_date between '", startdate, "' and '", enddate, 
      "' And nvl(m_sms_send, 0)=0 AND m.unitcode = '",unitcode,"' And rownum <= 10"
   });
   return SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(CnSettings.cnString1, CommandType.Text, commandText);
}
```

Comment: your `SqlHelper.ExecuteReader` return wrong type, so or use `SqlDataReader` insted of `OracleDataReader` or modify your helper

Comment: show code of SqlHelper.ExecuteReader - propably return wrong type

Answer (score 2):

`SqlHelper.ExecuteReader` is returning the wrong type - a `SqlDataReader`; when your `getWeightmntInfoForCenter` method is expecting to return an `OracleDataReader`.

If you want to return the `SqlDataReader`, you could change the signature of this method:

```
public IDataReader getWeightmntInfoForCenter(...)
```

This specifies that this method will return a class implementing `IDataReader`, but doesn't specify precisely what concrete type that will be, which means you can return either an `SqlDataReader` *or* an `OracleDataReader` (as both classes implement this interface).

Comment: Your solution is nice but what if he needs a specific type method like:  `reader.GetOracleString(0);`

Comment: @YairNevet Then he should go with one of the other answers ;) - though, saying that, based on the name of the method, any calling method should be independent of implementation-specific details like `GetOracleString`.

Comment: Or maybe to up-cast it: `getWeightmntInfoForCenter(...) as OracleDataReader`

Comment: @YairNevet Yes, casting would be an option but would generally suggest something has been designed badly somewhere - you shouldn't call a method that needs an `IDataReader` if you need something that might not be available on the object that's returned, otherwise it's pointless using the interface in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getWeightmntInfoForCenter` method signature return `type` is `OracleDataReader`, while you are actually returning `SqlDataReader`, look:

```
return SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(...
```

Change your code to call: [`OracleCommand.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method so that `OracleDataReader` will be returned properly.

Do it like that:

```
    public OracleDataReader GetWeightmntInfoForCenter(string startdate, string enddate, string unitcode)
    {
        string commandText = string.Concat(new[]
            {
                "select m.unitcode unit_code, to_char(tran_date, 'dd-MON-yy') m_date, to_char(m_purchy) m_number, net AS n_weight, to_number(substr(g.ryot_code,5)) m_grow, to_number(substr(g.ryot_code,1,4)) m_vill, g.mob g_phoneno,m.s_purchy indent_number from sisl_purpurchase m,cn_ryot_mst g where m.unitcode=g.unit_code and lpad(v_code,4,0)||lpad(f_code,5,0)=g.ryot_code And length(g.mob)=10 And m.tran_date between '"
                , startdate, "' and '", enddate, "' And nvl(m_sms_send, 0)=0 AND m.unitcode = '", unitcode,
                "' And rownum <= 10"
            });

        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(CnSettings.cnString1))
        {
            var command = new OracleCommand(commandText, connection);
            connection.Open();
            return command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SqlHelper.ExecuteReader()` returns an object of type `SqlDataReader` but the return type of your method is `OracleDataReader` which is different.

You could change your method signature to return [`DbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. Both specific data reader classes for Oracle and Sql Server derive from that generic one:

```
public DbDataReader getWeightmntInfoForCenter(...)
{
    ...
}
```

On the other hand if you're working with an Oracle database you can't use `SqlHelper.ExecuteReader()` because it's a specific implementation for SQL Server. Have a look at [`OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4kxd8h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Yes I tried it, but it wont work @Davecz ans is correct. I made changes in my sqlhelper file and it is working fine.